# menu java, como resuelvo estos problemas?

Tags: java

tengo esta consigna

Hacer un sistema que tenga un menú de opciones:

```
1 - ingresar una nota
2 - ver todas
3 - calcular promedio
4 - ver materia con la nota mas alta
0 - salir
```

Que debe hacer lo siguiente:

```
1 - Para ingresar la nota, pide un nombre de materia y luego la nota de esa materia
2 - muestra todas las notas, una por linea , mostrando el nombre de la materia y la nota
3 - calcula el promedio de todas las notas
4 - muestra el nombre de la materia que tenga la mejor nota
0 - fin del programa
```

y logre hacer en código esto

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tp8_6 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String materias [] = new String[3];
        int notas [] = new int [3];
        int menu = 0;
       while(menu != 5){
           System.out.println("bienvenido al menu de notas");
           System.out.println("1 - ingresar una nota\n" +
                   "2 - ver todas\n" +
                   "3 - calcular promedio\n" +
                   "4 - ver materia con la nota mas alta\n" +
                   "5 - salir\n");
           menu = in.nextInt();
           switch(menu) {
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("nombre de la materia");
                   String materia = in.next();
                   for (int z = 0; z < materias.length; z++) {
                       materias[z] = materia;

                   }
                   System.out.println("nota de la materia ingresada");
                   int nota = in.nextInt();
                   for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
                       notas[i] = nota;

                   }
                   break;
               case 2:
                   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                       System.out.println(materias[i]);
                   }
                   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                       System.out.println(notas[i]);
                   }
                   break;
               case 3:

                   int total = 0;
                   for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){

                       total+=notas[i];
                   }
                   int promedio = total / 3;
                   System.out.println("el promedio total es: " + promedio);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   int mayor = 0;
                   for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ){

                       if(mayor == i){
                           mayor = i;
                       }
                   }
                   System.out.println(mayor);
                   break;
               case 5:
                   break;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

el codigo funciona todo bien MENOS el case 1 que no respeta los espacios que tiene los arrays (en este caso 3)

y el case 2 que imprime 3 veces lo ultimo ingresado... no entiendo porque estan esos 2 errores. todo lo demas funciona correctamente!

les pido que usen cosas simples al nivel de lo que ven en el codigo, arraylist no vi todavia y no se si puedo usarlo en esta tarea :( solamente vi hasta arrays y switch, antes de eso if else, bucles, boolean, operadores matematicos. lo basico

muchas gracias de ante mano :)

Comment: El codigo no hace lo que pide tu ejercicio. De que array hablas para el caso 1? en el caso 1, estas pidiendo un numero una sola vez, y lo estas guardando en 3 posiciones del array.. y de ahi, los problemas que ves despues. Te recomendaria que aprendas a hacer debug con la ide que uses. De esa forma, vas a poder seguir tu codigo linea por linea y ver que tiene cada variable en cada punto.

Comment: El case 4 no tiene pinta de funcionar tampoco. Fíjate que en el case 1 estás metiendo en TODAS las posiciones del array lo que acabas de leer. Si pones "matemáticas", en el bucle haces materias[0] = "matemáticas", materias[1] = "matemáticas", materias[2] = "matemáticas". Y lo mismo con las notas. Tienes que llevar un control de qué posición toca almacenar ahí.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código cuenta con dos nuevas variables:

```java
int TOTAL_NOTAS = 3;
int posicionActual = 0;
```

`TOTAL_NOTAS` controla el tamaño máximo que tienen tus *arreglos*
y facilita cambiar su tamaño en un futuro. `posicionActual` nos dice
donde nos encontramos dentro del arreglo y a la vez cuantos *espacios*
estamos usando realmente (pero puedes y **se recomienda** usar otra variable para esto).
Al ingresar nuevas notas es importante comprobar si aún tenemos espacio para ello:

```java
if (posicionActual < TOTAL_NOTAS) {
…
}
```

Empleando `posicionActual` podemos decidir donde *colocar* la nueva información:

```java
notas[posicionActual] = nota;
```

Y una vez hecho esto tenemos que incrementar su valor para evitar
sobrescribir la información una y otra vez:

```java
posicionActual++;
```

Sí nuestro arreglo no contiene elementos y realizamos operaciones sobre el
 podemos obtener errores difíciles de detectar, comprobar que tenemos al menos un
elemento es obligatorio:

```java
if (posicionActual > 0) {
…
}
```

Para realizar el listado debemos conocer la cantidad de elementos que hemos
 usado, **no nos sirve imprimir cincuenta líneas sí solo las primeras
 dos contienen información**. Nuevamente `posicionActual` nos ayuda con eso:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < posicionActual; i++) {
    System.out.println(" " + materias[i] + " = " + notas[i]);
}
```

Calcular el promedio es un caso similar, sí tenemos espacio para cincuenta
 notas y solo usamos dos pues…
`promedio = total / 50;` nos dará un resultado erróneo. Una variable que lleve
 la cuenta nos evitara dolores de cabeza:
`promedio = total / posicionActual;`
Para obtener la nota más alta ocupamos comparar el registro actual con
el ultimo más alto, sí el registro actual es mayor ocupara su lugar como el mas alto.
Además requerimos saber en que posición dentro del arreglo se encuentra, mostrar el
número ocho en pantalla no nos dice nada:

```java
if (notas[i] > mayor){
    indice = i;
    mayor = notas[i];
}
```

**Siempre debes comprobar** que **los valores que recibes** son los correctos,
pero creo que tienes la capacidad para realizar esas comprobaciones por tu cuenta.

Y finalmente… Este es el código completo:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tp8_6_2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int TOTAL_NOTAS = 3;
        int posicionActual = 0;
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String materias[] = new String[TOTAL_NOTAS];
        int notas[] = new int[TOTAL_NOTAS];
        int menu = 0;
        
        while (menu != 5) {
            System.out.println("Bienvenido al menú de notas");
            System.out.println("1 - Ingresar una nota\n" +
                "2 - Ver todas\n" +
                "3 - Calcular promedio\n" +
                "4 - Ver materia con la nota mas alta\n" +
                "5 - Salir\n");
            menu = in.nextInt();
            
            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    String materia;
                    int nota;
                    
                    if (posicionActual < TOTAL_NOTAS) {
                        System.out.print("Nombre de la materia: ");
                        materia = in.next();
                        materias[posicionActual] = materia;
                        
                        System.out.print("Nota de la materia ingresada: ");
                        nota = in.nextInt();
                        notas[posicionActual] = nota;
                        
                        // Para evitar que todo se vea muy «pegado»
                        System.out.println();
                        
                        posicionActual++;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("¡Ya no puedo ingresar más notas!\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 2:
                    if (posicionActual > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Lista de notas:");
                        
                        for(int i = 0; i < posicionActual; i++) {
                            System.out.println(" " + materias[i] + " = " + notas[i]);
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No hay notas que mostrar.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 3:
                    int total = 0, promedio = 0;
                    
                    if (posicionActual > 0) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < posicionActual; i++) {
                            total += notas[i];
                        }
                        
                        promedio = total / posicionActual;
                        
                        System.out.println("El promedio es: " + promedio + "\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Aún no ingresa notas.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 4:
                    int mayor = 0, indice = 0;
                    
                    if (posicionActual > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < posicionActual; i++){
                            if (notas[i] > mayor){
                                mayor = notas[i];
                                indice = i;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println(materias[indice] + " es la" +
                            " materia con la nota más alta: " +
                            notas[indice] + "\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Aún no ingresa notas.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 5:
                    // Un mensaje de salida.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

El problema está en tu lógica

```java
String materia = in.next();
for (int z = 0; z < materias.length; z++) {
    materias[z] = materia;
}
```

agregas en todas las posiciones de tu arreglo el mismo valor

para corregirlo cambia a:

```java
//String materia = in.next();
for (int z = 0; z < materias.length; z++) {
    materias[z] = in.next();
}
```

De esta forma te va a solicitar el ingreso N veces (en tu caso 3).

Y de la misma forma para las notas:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
   notas[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

Ademas con esto tu segundo Case donde muestras la información también se corrige.

Comment: Muy usable no es introducir todos los nombres de las materias seguidos y a continuación las notas. Y menos cuando va en contra del enunciado/requerimiento: "1 - Para ingresar la nota, pide un nombre de materia y luego la nota de esa materia"

Comment: Solo adapte al código que tiene

Comment: Pero se trata de corregir el código que tiene para que cumpla los requisitos, ¿no?

Comment: de hecho con eso cumple, tu quieres agregar una funcionalidad que no le solicitaron asumiendo que es mejor de la forma en la que tu piensas. Por eso agregas `Muy usable no es introducir todos los nombres de las materias seguidos y a continuación las notas. `

Comment: No sé con qué cumple. Ahí arriba se describe el punto 1 como ingresar UNA nota y a luego se describe como pedir el nombre de la materia y luego su nota. Usable sigue sin ser tu interpretación si tienes que meter 20 materias y luego sus 20 notas, sin indice y sin nada.

Comment: Por que no solo revisas el codigo de la pregunta, ahi especifica ingresar primero las materias despues las notas. no entiendes eso? simplemente agrego las correciones al codigo ingresado no la implementacion por mi cuenta.